# Windows phone 8.1 Phone App: DataTransferManager UI not showing when it view on Windows Phone 10

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, sharing, windows-10-mobile

In my windows phone 8.1 phone app project I am trying to make a share option.

But when I click on the button (Share) the Share UI is not showing up in Windows Phone 10, but it works fine in Windows Phone 8.1

Here is the code

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{

DataTransferManager dataTransferManager = DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView();
                dataTransferManager.DataRequested +=new TypedEventHandler<DataTransferManager,
                DataRequestedEventArgs>(this.DataTransferManager_DataRequested);

}



private void DataTransferManager_DataRequested(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs e)
{

try
{
DataRequest request = e.Request;
request.Data.Properties.Title = "Article";
request.Data.SetText("\nYou have been shared with an article");
}

catch (Exception ex)
{
throw ex;
}

}




private void ShareAppBarButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI();
}
```

I have tried setting different properties in the DataRequested event but still nothing happens.

Does anyone know what it could be?

Thank you.

Comment: Same problem herein my case. Any solutions?